# Why does join not work with let clause storing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

The following code works fine in Linq, when I join the tables using the where clause

```
var result =
    from dist in distributors
    let mainDistributorStates = new List<string> {"TX", "OR"}
    from mdist in mainDistributorStates 
    where dist.State == mdist
    select dist;
```

But the following doesn't, showing the comiler error

> mainDistributorStates does not exist in the current context.

```
var result =
    from dist in distributors
    let mainDistributorStates = new List<string> {"TX", "OR"}
    join mdist in mainDistributorStates 
     on dist.State equals mdist
    select dist;
```

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause):

> In a query expression, it is sometimes useful to store the result of a sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses.

Since the let clause stores an IEnumerable, why can't it be used like any other data source in linq?

Comment: Is it linq-to-sql? What is `distributors`? Can you post a *complete* exception please?

Comment: There is no Exception, this is a compiler error and it is a linq-to-objects

Comment: Read the question please https://dotnetfiddle.net/IizsXl

Comment: Your first example is very inefficient btw, because the `let mainDistributorStates = ...` expression is reevaluated (and the `List<string>` rebuilt) **for every element** in `distributors`. Looking at the compiled CIL, Linq is not performing a "real" JOIN, it's actually generating a Cartesian Product and then filtering the results (via `Select( Where( SelectMany( Select ) ) )`) - it's pretty ugly to look at and should not be used in production code, imo.

Comment: I know, it's just an example to showcase the issue. But your comment made me realize why I can't join these two together! It's because it will create one enumerable per from item and not one enumerable overall, with which it could join.